# How do i make this batch file start and after 2 hours it will shutdown and start the same program?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Okay, so I made a Rust server. I'm starting the program with a `.bat` file. The `.bat` file contains:

```
rust_server.exe -batchmode -hostname "XtraRust" -cfg "cfg/server.cfg" -maxplayers 25 -port 28015 -datadir "serverdata/" -map "rust_island_2013"
```

How do I make a batch file to start this and shutdown after 2 hours and then start the program again with everything automated?

I tried using:

```
@echo off
:loop
start rust_server.exe
timeout /t 1200 >null
taskkill /f /im rust_server.exe >nul
goto loop
```

But it starts opening the file every 0.25 sec, which will lead to a computer crash.

Comment: Why does everyone try to do everything in a batch file, when Windows has a perfectly usable Task Scheduler? A scheduled task that runs every two hours that executes the `taskkill` and then starts rust would be absolutely perfect for this, instead of struggling so hard to do it in a batch file.

Comment: I have never used task scheduler before. How do i make it kill the task after 2 hours and then start again automatically?

Comment: Task scheduler is not meant to the work, but to start a process. You can tell the scheduler to start a batchfile every two hours, and the batchfile will do the work (killing and starting), and then exit, until restarted again two hours later.

Answer (score 0):

I have a server too. Same problem. There is only one way to make the server restart after 2 hours because batch is busy preforming the command start rust_server.exe. It will not stop preforming the command until you restart the server manually. The only way to do this is another batch file.

```
@echo off
:loop
timeout /t <insert seconds here>
taskkill /im rust_server.exe
goto loop
```

the only problem with this is that it will possibly corrupt the server. My server, which is Minecraft, you can add a plugin (or modification) to automatically save the game every 2 hours. I do not know if you can modify the code of a rust server. But if you can, make it so it will save the game before your new batch file restarts the server.

as for the batch file to open the server, use this:

```
@echo off
color b9
mode 1000
:main
cls
rust_server.exe -batchmode -hostname "XtraRust" -cfg "cfg/server.cfg" -maxplayers 25 -port 28015 -datadir "serverdata/" -map "rust_island_2013"
```

Lol I like those colors. "Mode 1000" makes it full screen.

Comment: Its really late, but thanks for your answer, im going to try that later.

Answer (score 0):

There is no apparent reason why your batch acts as you report.

It would appear that `timeout` is failing. Is it located on your `path`? It should be in `c:\windows\system32` on a standard installation.

You are outputting `timeout` to `null` which will create a file called `null`. Too many `l`s to output to your `nul` device. This should not cause your problem however.

You could try

choice /t 1200 /d y >nul

which should effectively do the same thing.

I'm curious about your invocation of `rust_server.exe` in your batch - without parameters, when you say that you have a batch file to invoke `rust_server.exe` with parameters. You haven't called that file `rust_server.exe.bat` by any chance, have you? Not that that would cause the problem - just a strange idea.

I see no real extra value in using `task scheduler` for what you require. You need to be able to ensure that the scheduled job is run under the correct credentials - username, password, permissions and path considerations. Then you'd need to schedule a batch to `taskkill` the existing server and start a new one.

I was subjected to an hour-plus screeching session from a "systems administrator" who claimed that being unable to start scheduled tasks was a "well-known" problem that "no-one in the world has been able to solve". The fact that Microsoft had released a fix three years earlier (and it had been installed) was immaterial (she wouldn't stop ranting to listen to that.)

So perhaps that's why I'm allergic to Task Scheduler - you may need to patch your version. YMMV.